# XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync suddenly stops working and always returns an exception?

Tags: xml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

This method:

```
var xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri("your XML url here"));
```

Suddenly stops working and always returns an exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Is there another way to load xml document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Asynchronous XmlReader to read xml from uri link:

```
    private async void ReadXml(string uri)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "NodeName")
                    {
                        string nodeContent = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```